# Multiple grouped charts with altair

Tags: dataframe, charts, altair, errorbar

[image]

My data has 4 attributes: dataset (D1/D2), model (M1/M2), layer (L1/L2), scene (S1/S2). I can make a chart grouped by scenes and then merge plots horizontally and vertically (pic above).
However, I would like to have 'double grouping' by scene and dataset, like merging the D1 and D2 plots by placing blue/orange bars from next to each other but with different opacity or pattern/hatch.

Basically something like this (pretend that the black traits are a hatch pattern).

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce the first plot

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import argparse
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import altair as alt
alt.renderers.enable('altair_viewer')

np.random.seed(0)

################################################################################

model_keys = ['M1', 'M2']
data_keys = ['D1', 'D2']
scene_keys = ['S1', 'S2']
layer_keys = ['L1', 'L2']

ys = []
models = []
dataset = []
layers = []
scenes = []

for sc in scene_keys:
    for m in model_keys:
        for d in data_keys:
            for l in layer_keys:
                for s in range(10):
                    data_y = list(np.random.rand(10) / 10)
                    ys += data_y
                    scenes += [sc] * len(data_y)
                    models += [m] * len(data_y)
                    dataset += [d] * len(data_y)
                    layers += [l] * len(data_y)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------


df = pd.DataFrame({'Y': ys,
                   'Model': models,
                   'Dataset': dataset,
                   'Layer': layers,
                   'Scenes': scenes})

bars = alt.Chart(df, width=100, height=90).mark_bar().encode(
    # field to group columns on
    x=alt.X('Scenes:N',
        title=None,
        axis=alt.Axis(
            grid=False,
            title=None,
            labels=False,
        ),
    ),
    # field to use as Y values and how to calculate
    y=alt.Y('Y:Q',
        aggregate='mean',
        axis=alt.Axis(
            grid=True,
            title='Y',
            titleFontWeight='normal',
        ),
    ),
    # field to use for sorting
    order=alt.Order('Scenes',
        sort='ascending',
    ),
    # field to use for color segmentation
    color=alt.Color('Scenes',
        legend=alt.Legend(orient='bottom',
            padding=-10,
        ),
        title=None,
    ),
)

error_bars = alt.Chart(df).mark_errorbar(extent='ci').encode(
    x=alt.X('Scenes:N'),
    y=alt.Y('Y:Q'),
)

text = alt.Chart(df).mark_text(align='center',
    baseline='line-bottom',
    color='black',
    dy=-5 # y-shift
).encode(
    x=alt.X('Scenes:N'),
    y=alt.Y('mean(Y):Q'),
    text=alt.Text('mean(Y):Q', format='.1f'),
)

chart_base = bars + error_bars + text

chart_base = chart_base.facet(
    # field to use to use as the set of columns to be represented in each group
    column=alt.Column('Layer:N',
        # header=alt.Header(
            # labelFontStyle='bold',
        # ),
        title=None,
        sort=list(set(models)), # get unique indices
    ),
    spacing={"row": 0, "column": 15},
)

def unique(sequence):
    seen = set()
    return [x for x in sequence if not (x in seen or seen.add(x))]

for i, m in enumerate(unique(models)):
    chart_imnet = chart_base.transform_filter(
        alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='Dataset', equal='D1'),
    ).transform_filter(
        alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='Model', equal=m)
    )
    chart_places = chart_base.transform_filter(
        alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='Dataset', equal='D2')
    ).transform_filter(
        alt.FieldEqualPredicate(field='Model', equal=m)
    )

    if i == 0:
        title_params = dict({'align': 'center', 'anchor': 'middle', 'dy': -10})
        chart_imnet = chart_imnet.properties(title=alt.TitleParams('D1', **title_params))
        chart_places = chart_places.properties(title=alt.TitleParams('D2', **title_params))

    chart_places = alt.concat(chart_places,
        title=alt.TitleParams(
            m,
            baseline='middle',
            orient='right',
            anchor='middle',
            angle=90,
            # dy=10,
            dx=30 if i == 0 else 0,
        ),
    )

    if i == 0:
        chart = (chart_imnet | chart_places).resolve_scale(x='shared')
    else:
        chart = (chart & (chart_imnet | chart_places).resolve_scale(x='shared'))

chart.save('test.html')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, I don't know a good answer, but once https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/pull/2528 is accepted you can use the `xOffset` encoding channel as such:

```py
alt.Chart(df, height=90).mark_bar(tooltip=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("Scenes:N"),
    y=alt.Y("mean(Y):Q"),
    color=alt.Color("Scenes:N"),
    opacity=alt.Opacity("Dataset:N"),
    xOffset=alt.XOffset("Dataset:N"),
    column=alt.Column('Layer:N'),
    row=alt.Row("Model:N")
).resolve_scale(x='independent')
```

Which will result in:
[image]

See [Colab Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1qDO8g4BaudL9NJ7-QS3naEsaag_ueHKJ?usp=sharing) or [Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/gist/4ca51bef6ee9cf18fc619322bc16124a/vl5_xoffset_facet.json)

**EDIT**

To control the opacity and legend names one can do as such

```py
alt.Chart(df, height=90).mark_bar(tooltip=True).encode(
    x=alt.X("Scenes:N"),
    y=alt.Y("mean(Y):Q"),
    color=alt.Color("Scenes:N"),
    opacity=alt.Opacity("Dataset:N", 
                        scale=alt.Scale(domain=['D1', 'D2'], 
                                        range=[0.2, 1.0]), 
                        legend=alt.Legend(labelExpr="datum.label == 'D1' ? 'D1 - transparent' : 'D2 - full'")),
    xOffset=alt.XOffset("Dataset:N"),
    column=alt.Column('Layer:N'),
    row=alt.Row("Model:N")
).resolve_scale(x='independent')
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!
Just one question. Is there a way to change the legend for the dataset? I guess that black is for 'full color' and gray for 'transparent color', but it is confusing. It would be great to either 1) change the legend markers to text (with 'full'/'transparent' in place of black/gray squares), or 2) have a legend with all 4 colors and entries S1 D1, S1 D2, S2 D1, S2 D2. Thanks!

Comment: Also, the 'full color' is not really full as in the original plot, but still a bit transparent. Is it possible to have it with no transparency at all?

Comment: See edited answer. I was not able to replace the square opacity block, but with a `labelExpr` one can replace the text to something different. Using scale domain and range you can control the opacity.